# weird symbol getting appended at the end

Tags: c++

I am trying to read characters from a file and writing them to another. The problem is, though everything is being written, a weird symbol is getting appended in the next line of write file. My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    FILE *f, *g;
    int ch;
    f = fopen("readfile", "r");
    g = fopen("writefile", "w");
    while(ch != EOF){
            ch = getc(f);
            putc(ch, g);
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(g);
return 0;
}
```

What may be the reason for that?

Comment: Could you **please** just use [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)?

Comment: By the way you are using uninited variable.

Comment: i initiated ch to zero, still the error occurs

Comment: @Griwes: The performance of fstream is often lower than a C FILE. It has to do more work. So it's not always a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you write `ch` to the other file before you check if it's `EOF`, so that one gets written too.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens if you check the return value of getc() AFTER already using that return value.

```
// simple fix
ch = getc(f);
while (ch != EOF) {
    putc(ch, g);
    ch = getc(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The weird symbol is the EOF constant.

```
ch = getc(f); // we've read a symbol, or EOF is returned to indicate end-of-file
putc(ch, g); // write to g whether the read operation was successful or not
```

The fix is

```
ch = getc(f);
while (ch != EOF)
{
    putc(ch, g);
    ch = getc(f);
}
```